# Is it possible to connect each and every pin of two IC's together and increase perfomance?

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor, semiconductors, diy

I am a newbie to electronics.
I have a crazy idea in my mind to create a PC with 32 bit microcontrollers.

I chose the [ATSAMV71J20](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATSAMV71J20) chip. The processor has a maximum CPU speed of 300MHz.

If I connect all pins of the CPUs together (except power pins which will cause current drop) and increase the maximum CPU speed will the speed increase from 300MHz to n(300MHz) where n is the number of CPUs? If not how can I run resource hungry programs with multiple CPUs?

Comment: That's a bit like putting a car on top of another car and hoping something good will come out of it.

Comment: You can't double the heartbeat (ps) of two human beings by forcing them to hold their hands together. the clock speed of a microcontroller is an internal oscillation made by specific hardware. usually another approach is used for getting higher performance from a CPU; a multi-core CPU.

Comment: "*... except power pins which will cause current drop ...*" The power pins are the only two pins that you *can* connect together. I don't know why you think there would be "a current drop". Usually all the chips are powered in parallel.

Comment: I said like if i have a source of 100mA in wire A. if i connect A to two processors each requiring 100mA, then there will be definitely a current drop!. Don't mistaken me if what I said is wrong

Comment: If this worked the Bitcoin miners would all be doing it.

Comment: If you connect an additional processor requiring 100mA, there doesn't need to be a current drop. If you have a voltage regulator that can source more than 200 mA, there will be no current drop nor voltage drop.

Comment: Hi Pranesh, The way microcontrollers work, they follow a certain set of instructions to run a program. Having parallel microcontrollers cannot be used to do 'more' in the classical sense. If you have 3 cars with a maximum speed of 100km/h, tying them all together wont make them go faster, it will probably cause some accidents when they collide with each other due to speed variations. The analogy applies to micro controllers. I would recommend go through some tutorials on how you can setup and run microcontroller programs, then re-evaluate the thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

No, by connecting all their pins together won't run faster (to be fair it won't work at all). Certainly you can create circuits with n processors (from now on also called cores), but there are certain requirements.

ONE) While they can share address space they must have also their own, private space where to have their data or instructions without interference.

TWO) Access to the public address space must be controlled by assigning priorities to the cores. A core modifying what another core is reading can have unexpected results.

THREE) Software must be written to take advantage of multi-core systems. A program written to be executed in a single cpu processor will be executed by a single core in a multiple-cpu-computer.

If you want to open Pandora's Box of parallel computing my piece of advice would be to start with the basics. Back when the 8 and 16 bit microprocessors roamed freely as state-of-the-art microprocessors it was common in consoles and arcade systems to integrate more than a single processor, sometimes for compatibility, other times to break down complex problems at decent execution times. For example, Sega Mega Drive / Genesys and Neo-Geo (AES/MVS) have 68000 and Z80 microprocessors and there are arcades like "Airwolf" which have three synchronized Z80 cpus. Before doing anything complex, study the synchronization circuits these systems had and once you comprehend them experiment with yours.

Answer (score 0):

You basically described a multi-core processor (which is common to find on ARM chips). You could split up your processes between the two chips (e.g., have one chip control half of your functionality, and the other the other half) then set up a way for them to communicate to each other to coordinate when they have to.

Better yet, buy a single chip that has two cores built into it. That makes coordinating actions between the two "chips" even faster - and you would effectively be putting all the pins together.

So yes, you can "go faster" by having two cores instead of one, but it would not go 2x faster since there will be some overhead needed to coordinate between the two chips.

Comment: Thank you! Can you show me some reference links which tells me about how to implement parallel computing

Comment: Its just like getting n people to dig a hole. You just need to ensure they aren’t digging the exact piece of earth.

Comment: Here's an example using freeRTOS on an arduino platform on an ESP32 https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/esp32-dual-core-programming-using-arduino-ide. And another using keil https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-for-LPC4350-Cortex-M4F-and-Cortex-M0-Keil.html. it's more complicated than single core and works especially nicely with RTOS since it manages coordination for you a bit.

Comment: Adding to my above comment: the simplest thing is to have one controller responding to one set of sensors and the other responding to a different set, and send data between the two controllers over some serial link (I2C, spi, uart) when needed.

Comment: Consider also [this law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) which would also limit how much an algorithm / program can be sped up by parallel processors.